# AS3 - How can objects that appear randomly never touch each other?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have two objects that appear randomly on stage, but i want them to never touch each other when they appear.

```
object1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
object1.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
object2.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
object2.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
```

Comment: Yeah, well, what have you tried? One way to accomplish this is to spawn the first object at a random place, spawn the second object at a random place, perform a hittest on both objects, if its true, change the coordinates of either object, hittest again etc. until the hittest is false.

Answer (score 0):

[As @DodgerThud has mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724072/as3-how-can-objects-that-appear-randomly-never-touch-each-other#comment49505410_30724072); the way to go about this problem is to repeatedly attempt to place the next object until it meets your criteria (not colliding with another object). This is a perfect example of what a `while` loop can be used for, something like:

```
while (!object1.hitTestObject(object2))
{
    object1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    object1.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 objects that appears on the stage, then is easy. In EnterFrame event you just put an if condition

```
    if(!obj1.hitTestObject(obj2)) {
        obj1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        obj1.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }
```

but if you have many objects, then you have to loop through all the objects and check the same condition.

```
for(var i:int=0; i<yourObjNumber; i++) {
      var hits:boolean = false;
      if(!obj1.hitTestObject(getChildAt(i))) {
           hits = true;     
      }
      if(hits) {
            obj1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            obj1.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
      }
}
```

Hope this helps!
**Have a great day!**